# Spring boot Multiple routes with multiple JWT

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I need to implement spring JWT security for my end points.. I have 2 routes - 1 for internal and 2nd for external. I tried to add the code below but both my filters are executing for any requests..
I can add a logic in the filter based on the url.. But I didnt feel thats the right approach. Please let me know what would be the right approach and how to solve it?

```
http
   .csrf().disable()
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/internal/**") 
       .authenticated()
   .and()
   .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationInternalFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/external/**")
   .authenticated()
   .and()
   .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationExternalFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);



public class ExternalAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Its hitting here  - External");//GET THE Information and build Authentication object..


        //  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}


public class InternalAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Its hitting here - Internal");//GET THE Information and build Authentication object..


        //  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Both internal and external code is executing for any request.
sample request
/internal/abc,
/external/xyz   .. Both cases both filters are being called..

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can split your security settings into two different configuration classes and mark them with e.g. `@Order(1)` and `@Order(2)` annotations. One config will deal with the `/internal` endpoints and one with the `/external`. In the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method, first, specify which endpoints you wish to configure and then apply your settings.

See an example of one config below, the second config will be analogical:

```java
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Order(1)
    public class ExternalEndpointsSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/internal/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationInternalFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats exactly I found in the link below..
-1
down vote
accept
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/samples-web.md#sample-multi-http-web-configuration.. I answered myself but someone deleted it